# Fastest way to implement _mm256_mullo_epi4 using AVX2

Tags: c, x86-64, intrinsics, avx, avx2

For a research problem I need a very efficient 4 bits multiplication (only the low 4 bit are needed) implementation using AVX2/AVX instructions.

My current approach is:

```
__m256i _mm256_mullo_epi4(const __m256i a, const __m256i b) {
    __m256i mask_f_0 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x000f);
    __m256i tmp_mul_0 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(a, b), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_1 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   4), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   4)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_2 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   8), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   8)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_3 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,  12), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,  12)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp1 = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp_mul_0, _mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_1, 4));
    __m256i tmp2 = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp1, _mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_2, 8));
    __m256i tmp  = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp2, _mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_3, 12));
    return tmp;
}
```

This implementation leverages the relative expensive `_mm256_mullo_epi16` instruction 4 times to compute each 4bit `limb` in separate.
Can this be done somehow faster? To put it more precisely: is it possible to reduce the number of needed instructions?

Comment: Thank you, give me a moment to add a simple benchmarking script. Regarding the second question: I think it would be useless to add my runtime/benchmark data, as with high probability we have different CPUs which are not comparable. And this is the functional problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch After the edit around 12.45 MEST, the question seems fine and answerable (in the positive or negative) to me. What more do you want? And: If the edit was predictable, why didn't you predict (and answer) it? And: Why are you so hostile?

Comment: For a question "How to make it faster?" I would still expect a measurement and a target. Note that for "faster" there are other ways than fewer instructions.  But you changed to "Fewer instructions?", I accept that as a clear and focused enough question. I point out that fewer instructions are not necessarily faster. Thanks, I retract my close vote.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I did predict and did point out what in that case is needed. The edit came afterwards, without anything in that direction. That is why I got a little direct. However, I do see what you mean by "hostile" and want to apologise to PingFloyd, in case they perceived that as hostile. I hope that I made up a little by demonstrating that on a reaction I do react - and cooperatively, not necessarily by getting what I asked for.

Comment: If you have AVX512 availability, you could either multiply twice as many nibbles at once in the same way, or try to use two _mm512_mullo_epi32 instructions (instead of 4), each calculating two nibble products. You can put (a1 << 12) & a0 in a 32 bit vector element and multiply by (b1 << 12) & b0 taking the results from bits [27:24] and [3:0] of the product. It would need to be benchmarked though to see if it is faster than what has already been proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an obvious way to reduce the number of multiplications, e.g., mask enough bytes of two inputs to get two separate products with one multiplication. Even `vpmaddubsw` is difficult to exploit, since it takes one operand as signed 8bit values (and would require a lot of shifting to get the nibbles in the correct positions).

You can however reduce the amount of shifting, at the cost of a few more maskings:

Pseudo code:

```
(a*b) & 0xf           = 0,0,0,ab
(a>>4)*(b&0xf0)       = *,*,ab,0
(a>>8)*(b&0xf00)      = *,ab,0,0
(a>>12)*(b&0xf000)    = ab,0,0,0
```

With intrinsics (untested):

```
__m256i _mm256_mullo_epi4(const __m256i a, const __m256i b) {
    __m256i mask_000f = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x000f);
    __m256i mask_00f0 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x00f0);
    __m256i mask_0f00 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x0f00);
    __m256i mask_f000 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0xf000);
    __m256i tmp_mul_0 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(a, b), mask_000f);
    __m256i tmp_mul_1 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,  4), _mm256_and_si256(b, mask_00f0)), mask_00f0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_2 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,  8), _mm256_and_si256(b, mask_0f00)), mask_0f00);
    __m256i tmp_mul_3 =                  _mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a, 12), _mm256_and_si256(b, mask_f000));
    __m256i tmp1 = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp_mul_0, tmp_mul_1);
    __m256i tmp2 = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp_mul_2, tmp_mul_3);
    __m256i tmp  = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp1, tmp2);
    return tmp;
}
```

This requires 4 multiplications and 3 shifts, but 9 bit-operations,
compared to 4 multiplications, 9 shifts and 7-bit-operations (technically, masking `tmp_mul_3` was not necessary and a compiler might be able to optimize it away).

So overall 16 uops instead of 19.

Answer (score 3):

Your function looks pretty optimal to me already as there is no _mm256_mullo_epi8 intrinsic. Aside from switching the AVX512, I don't think there's much that can be done to speed this up. Having said that, the final 3 xors don't need to all be dependent on the previous results so you could re-arrange them as follows and hope to benefit from some instruction level parallelism.

```
__m256i _mm256_mullo_epi4(const __m256i a, const __m256i b) {
    __m256i mask_f_0 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x000f);
    __m256i tmp_mul_0 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(a, b), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_1 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   4), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   4)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_2 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   8), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   8)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp_mul_3 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,  12), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,  12)), mask_f_0);
    __m256i tmp1 = _mm256_xor_si256(tmp_mul_0, _mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_1, 4));
    __m256i tmp2 = _mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_3, 12), _mm256_slli_epi16(tmp_mul_2, 8));
    return _mm256_xor_si256(tmp1, tmp2);
}
```

I don't really know why but sometimes I've found intrinsics to work a bit faster if you use fewer intermediate results. If you don't mind sacrificing readability, you could compare the performance with the following version of the above function without the explicit declarations of the intermediate results.

```
    __m256i _mm256_mullo_epi4(const __m256i a, const __m256i b) {
        __m256i mask_f_0 = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x000f);
        return _mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(a, b), mask_f_0), 
_mm256_slli_epi16(_mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   4), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   4)), mask_f_0), 4)), 
_mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_slli_epi16(_mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,  12), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,  12)), mask_f_0), 12), 
_mm256_slli_epi16(_mm256_and_si256(_mm256_mullo_epi16(_mm256_srli_epi16(a,   8), _mm256_srli_epi16(b,   8)), mask_f_0), 8)));
    }
```

Comment: If jamming everything into one expression without temporaries is faster, your compiler did a bad job.  (Or you forgot to enable optimization).  I would not recommend that.  I haven't noticed bad code-gen with GCC or clang for intrinsics with temp variables.